# Appending Text to Android TextView but Non-Editable

Tags: android, textview

I want to append text to an android EditText view but I want that text to not be present in the popup editor.  To be clear I want to put units in the EditText.  So for example "10 gallons" but when the popup editor is displayed I only want to see and edit "10".  Then when the value is returned I want the " gallons" appended back on to the view.

Is this possible in an automatic way or do I have to track onTouch() events and have a listener for the keyboard and manually append the units again?

Comment: Any reason you would not just put the units as a label next to the edittext view?  Or as a "hint",  like "Enter the number of gallons"?

Comment: Well, I need the units to stay glued to the value (like 1 space or 2 spaces apart).  I think I am going to create a new widget, an extension of the textview that can handle 2 text values.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the onFocusChange method for EditText views would detect when a user is editing the text field. Try something like this..

```
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if (b) {
                ((EditText)view).setText(String.valueOf(value));
            } else {
                value = Integer.valueOf(((EditText)view).getText().toString());
                ((EditText)view).setText(value + " gallons");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes, that might work, or something like it.  But I think I will try to create a new widget, an extension of the textView.  I will post again once I get it working.

Comment: Sorry I assumed you meant you were using an EditText view. If you want a TextView with a pop-up dialog with similar functionality, yes subclassing TextView and implementing this in onTouch() might be the way to go.

Comment: No, sorry that was my mistake.  I meant EditText, not TextView. I have editted the original question.